# Android ,PagerSlidingTabStrip ,XML :app:pstsActivateTextColor - no resource identifier found

Tags: android

```
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
    app:pstsTextAllCaps="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    app:pstsIndicatorHeight="4dp"
    app:pstsActivateTextColor="#FF666666"
    app:pstsDeactivateTextColor="#FFCCCCCC"
    app:pstsDividerPadding ="30dp"
    app:pstsDividerColor="@android:color/white"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="#ec9512"/>
```

When trying to compile this code I get the error message `Error:(15) No resource identifier found for attribute 'pstsActivateTextColor' in package 'com.example.android.myapplication'`.

I am running `compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'`.
Can anybody help with this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the solution !I could not use these functions because they are not included in the oficial library yet , it ia just a pull request now! To change the color of selected tabs text you should to use not **compile 'com.astuetz:pagerslidingtabstrip:1.0.1'.** in the gradle but to connect the library like a module (here is description how to connect **library like a module** http://www.truiton.com/2015/02/android-studio-add-library-project/) and  override the code inside it ! 
in the **PagerSlidingTabStrip** class make onPageSelected method like this

```
@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {
    for(int i=0; i < mTabsLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
        TextView tv = (TextView) mTabsLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);
        if(i == position){
               tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        } else {
            tv.setTextColor(Color.GREY);
        }
    }
}
```

use this when your are setting up tabstrip when the activity is created..

```
  public void setUpTabStrip(){   

          //your other customizations related to tab strip...blahblah
          // Set first tab selected
mTabsLinearLayout = ((LinearLayout)tabStrip.getChildAt(0));
for(int i=0; i < mTabsLinearLayout.getChildCount(); i++){
    TextView tv = (TextView) mTabsLinearLayout.getChildAt(i);

    if(i == 0){
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    } else {
        tv.setTextColor(Color.GREY);
    }
}
```